# Test app through android phone

Tags: android, testapp

I am beginner in android. I want to test my app in real android device but choose which android version is confusing me. I know when build a android app, I need to determine the min and target API. So how to use the feature of higher API and still run in lower API, and which API I need in testing device, min or target?

And one more question, my android device unable to update to android 7.0 so I update by some rom (not through OTA), so is that ok ? or how that affect in testing app ?
Thank!

Answer (score 0):

From [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target)

targetSDK

> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.
>   This attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).

And minSDK specifies minimum Android version that will be able to use your app.